# Passing a value with ajax and catching with php

Tags: ajax, http, post, request

After 3 days and many lame questions on this community,i finnaly understand a little bit of the ajax post...still i couldnt find the answer for one little problem.How to catch the value passed by ajax,with php?

```
$(document).on('click','tr.listContractRow', function(e){
    var path = $(this).data('path');

    $.post("contract.php", {id: path}, function(data){
        alert("data sent and received: " + path);
    });
});
```

The values is sent, i've tested it,the alert shows up with the right value,i also checked the console log.But somehow i cant catch it with php....:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $var = $_POST['id']
    echo $var;
}
```

But without succes.Any ideas?
**UPDATE:**

```
echo '<table>';
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query){
echo '<tr class="listContractRow" data-path="'.$row['id'].'">';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: The 2nd code is from `contract.php` file? Do You have only this inside?

Comment: no of course not,i also have the content from where the ajax gets the path value

Comment: Can You add the content of Your `contract.php` file?

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos , this is what i have in my contract.php ( check the edit)

Comment: And where do You create Your `$query` variable?

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos , is it really necessary? that's not the point.Of course it has to be a query too...but that has nothing to do with the problem..

Comment: I'm asking, because I see no invalid code here. Your `contact.php` file should get `$_POST['id']` value with no problem. Did You tried to use `$.get` or `$.ajax` instead of `$.post`?

Comment: i tried with $.get and still the same problem..i will try with $.ajax too...i believe that even with ajax,the php has to be reloaded....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only visible thing I can see is that there is a missing semicolon in your php:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
   $var = $_POST['id'];
   echo $var;
}
```

I replicated your code and it is working in my dev environment.

Comment: Still I have to admit that seems strange to me that this is the error, since any more than average IDE should notice that syntax error...